# adding custom entries to LyX Outline: Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx, theorems

My question is about LyX and not LaTeX, but the answer will affect how I should format my LaTeX.

I rely on the LyX "Table of Contents" tab in the Outline side panel to quickly find section(s) or even individual paragraphs by beginning to type a keyword in the "Filter". Now, I also name some of my definitions and theorems with e.g. Insert>Short Title.

How do I make LyX pick up those as well to appear in its "Table of Contents"?